# Program crashing on cout with new line "\n"

Tags: c++, arrays, crash

This is my main class and when the program gets to the part in the main where it calls the calcAndDisplay, it crashes.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include "Chap1227.h"

using namespace std;

//function prototypes
double getBonusRate(double rate);
void columnsDashes();
void endPgm();


int main() {

    double rate = 0.0;

        //filling array
        int salesArray[10][4] = {{2400, 3500, 2000, 2750},
                                 {1500, 7000, 1000, 2225},
                                 {2600, 2450, 2100, 2999},
                                 {2790, 2240, 2500, 2885},
                                 {2100, 2600, 2300, 3000},
                                 {6300, 7000, 8000, 5550},
                                 {3300, 1850, 2950, 2100},
                                 {2700, 5500, 6000, 7200},
                                 {4700, 4800, 4900, 5100},
                                 {2375, 3300, 2550, 1925}};

        getBonusRate(rate);

        columnsDashes();

        //bonus object
        Bonus myBonus;

        myBonus.calcAndDisplay(salesArray, rate);

        endPgm();


    return 0;
}

// ***** getBonusRate function description *****
//
double getBonusRate(double rate)
{
    //display console title to user
    cout << "JM SALES BONUS CALCULATOR\n\n";

    //get bonus rate from user
    cout << "Enter bonus rate in decimal form: ";
    cin >> rate;
    cout << "\n\n";

    return rate;
}

// ***** columnsDashes function description *****
//
void columnsDashes()
{
    //display column headings and dashes to user
    cout << "Number     Sales($)     Bonus($)\n";
    cout << "------     --------     --------";
}

// ***** endPgm function description *****
//
void endPgm()
{
    //EOP message
    cout << "\n\nEnd of Program.";
}
```

This is the .h file that contains the calcAndDisplay, it was working but all the numbers printed with no spaces so I added the /n to the print statement and it's crashed ever since. I tried removing the /n but it still crashes. I'm not sure what the problem is.

```
#ifndef CHAP1227_H_
#define CHAP1227_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

// ***** CLASS DEFINITION *****
class Bonus
{
    public:
       Bonus();
       void calcAndDisplay(int salesArray[10][4], double rate);

    private:
       int totSales;
       int grandTotSales;
       double salesBonus;
       double bonusGrandTot;
};

// ***** CLASS IMPLEMENTATION *****
//default constructor
Bonus::Bonus()
{
    totSales = 0;
    grandTotSales = 0;
    salesBonus = 0.0;
    bonusGrandTot = 0.0;
}

//calcAndDisplay function
//
void Bonus::calcAndDisplay(int salesArray[10][4], double rate)
{



    for (int row = 0; row < 10; row += 1)
    {

        for (int column = 0; column < 4; column += 1)
        {

            totSales += salesArray[row][column];

        }
        cout << totSales + "\n";
    }

}


#endif /* CHAP1227_H_ */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm dubious of your claim:

> I tried removing the /n but it still crashes.

Because that's exactly where the problem is.

You need to change:

```
cout << totSales + "\n";
```

to:

```
cout << totSales << "\n";
```

You cannot ***add*** a double and a string without type conversion, but you can concatenate the streams. (Note you could convert the double to a string, but the above is more straight-forward).

Comment: thank you so much, I removed the \n but not the +, just got a little confused for a second.